# logging package in python - do_POST between two simple http servers

Tags: python, http, logging

I have two http servers that talk with each other.
the scenario is that serverA get a POST request from "outside" (not serverB, by:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8888
```

), then serverA sends POST request to serverB.

here are do_POST function for each server:

```
class serverA_handler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print "serverA got a POST from curl"    
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        print "POST = ", post_body
        print "serverA is sending POST to serverB"
        logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
        logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        logger.addHandler(HTTPHandler("localhost:9999", "/", method='POST'))
        logger.warning('sending POST to serverB')
        print "END DO_POST of serverA"
        return

class serverB_handler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print "serverB got a POST from serverA"    
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        print "POST = ", post_body
        print "\nEND DO_POST serverA" 
        return
```

I run both servers on different terminals, then start send POST request to serverA.

my problem is that with every curl post that I send to serverA, I see in serverB as if it recived all previous POST requests from serverA, plus a new one..
for example:

```
1. curl cmd -->   END DO_POST of serverA  ---> END DO_POST of serverB
2. curl cmd -->   END DO_POST of serverA  ---> END DO_POST of serverB
                                               END DO_POST of serverB
3. curl cmd -->   END DO_POST of serverA  ---> END DO_POST of serverB
                                               END DO_POST of serverB
                                               END DO_POST of serverB
```

and so on..
If I restarting serverA but keep serverB running, I see in the first cycle

```
curl cmd -->   END DO_POST of serverA  ---> END DO_POST of serverB (one time)
```

and as I continue the problem repeats itself..

What Is the problem with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming `addHandler` is to blame,  Every request made increments the handler count by 1.

Could you initiate the handler outside of the request?

Comment: thanks, it helps, but I still don't understand what  happened.. I defined logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger') locally in the function.. so it was supposed to vanish when returning
from docs.python: addHandler() - "Adds the specified handler hdlr to this logger." but my logger was a new one everytime